# Shiro cache size

Tags: caching, permissions, shiro

How to estimate size for Apache Shiro permissions cache?

For example, permissions strings are implemented in format:

```
<domain>:<resource_group>:<resource_name>:<permission>
```

for example

```
my-domain:resource-group-0001:resource-0001:permission-001
```

Would Shiro store all those strings as plain text?
In our case, we have 10,000+ users, 10,000+ resources and up 100 possible permissions. Of course only a fraction of all permutations would be present, but even then we are looking at 200M+ entries with potentially 10+ GB of data, which would be taxing for an in-memory cache.

The data would not be coming from a database in plain form, so no ehcache here. However, we do have to make this cache distributed, so current (smaller scale) implementation uses Redis.

Answer (score 0):

Estimating sizes really difficult. We (the SHIRO Team) haven't done it. You might be better of with a cache that will "forget" old entries.

Shiro will store more than just the permission String. You can see it here (1.9.x branch): [`AuthorizingRealm.java:317-337`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.9.x/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthorizingRealm.java#L317-L337)
The method will retrieve (and store) an [`AuthorizationInfo`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/848f1224b16ff3d99192eacf092ebbc737a08f39/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/AuthorizationInfo.java) object. That means, it will serialize this object containing:

```
Collection<String> getRoles();

Collection<String> getStringPermissions();

Collection<Permission> getObjectPermissions();
```

Now, it is different per user how many Roles and String- or ObjectPermissions they have. It may vary greatly, even within the same application.

The Permission is yet another nested structure. The [default implementation, `WildcardPermission`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.9.x/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/authz/permission/WildcardPermission.java), will internally it tear the String apart into multiple Collections:

```
private List<Set<String>> parts;
```

Then, the last thing to store is the cache Key, which is a `PrincipalCollection`. However, it is usually just a single Principal for most applications (ie a collection of size one).

---

If you need an estimate, you could extend the Realm you are using and override the method [`protected AuthorizationInfo getAuthorizationInfo(PrincipalCollection principals);`](https://github.com/apache/shiro/blob/1.9.x/core/src/main/java/org/apache/shiro/realm/AuthorizingRealm.java#L311)  to print the serialized size. However, this should only be done in a test environment.

---

I hope you now have an overview of what is being saved (and serialized). Let us know whether  this helps to do the numbers!

Comment: Not very encouraging, but thank you very much!